# How do you query the value of `mainClass` at the sbt command line?

Tags: scala, sbt

At the sbt command line, most variables from `build.sbt` can be looked up by just typing their name -- for example:

```
> libraryDependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3, junit:junit:latest.revision)
```

But this doesn't work with `mainClass`:

```
> mainClass
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 16, 2014 7:20:58 AM
```

Presumably this is because the way you set the value of `mainClass` isn't so simple -- you have to put things like this in `build.sbt`:

```
mainClass in (Compile, run)        := Some("com.example.MyClass")
mainClass in (Compile, packageBin) := Some("com.example.MyClass")
mainClass in (Test,    run)        := Some("com.example.MyClass")
mainClass in (Test,    packageBin) := Some("com.example.MyClass")
```

In fact, it turns out that `mainClass` isn't actually a plain value at all -- it is a `TaskKey`, not a `SettingKey`. So when you type its name at the sbt command line, I think sbt is actually running some code.

So... What do I type at the sbt command line to query, for example, the value of `mainClass in (Compile, run)`? (Or, all the values of `mainClass`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Settings do display their value by default if you enter their name on the command line, but tasks do not. `libraryDependencies` is a setting, that's why it shows its value by default.

`mainClass`, however, is a task. To display the value of a task, you have to explicitly use `show`:

```
> show mainClass
```

If you however want to see the value in a given scope, task and/or project you should fill out the necessary axes - see http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Scopes.html.

```
> show run::mainClass
[info] Some(com.example.Hello)

> show compile:mainClass
[info] Some(com.example.Hello)
```